# Discord.py Function that responds for all commands

Tags: discord.py

I am looking for something like an event that is triggered every time *any* command is invoked. Something like:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_command(ctx):
   ...
```

But I can't find anything for this. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok lol, I searched the docs for `on_command()` and it turns out that there is an event called `on_command()`, so... I guess this is for anyone who had the same question as me :)